# Maximal Elements in a Lower Set

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, order-theory

I have a collection of objects, and a feasibility property for sets of objects which is slow to compute. If a set is feasible then so is any subset. For example, it could be whether the set of things will fit into a certain-sized packing crate.

I want to compute all feasible sets (equivalently - all maximal feasible sets), minimizing the number of evaluations of the feasibility property (worst-case or average). Does anyone know of any theoretical work on this?

Bonus question - what if the cost to compute the property is linear (or superlinear) in the size of the set being evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to exact learning of monotone DNFs. This task is equivalent to learning all *minterms* of a monotone function, whereas you are interested in learning all *maxterms* of a monotone function, but the two problems are equivalent. (Look these terms up if you are not familiar with them.)

If the only queries you allow are *membership queries* (test whether a given set is feasible or not) then your problem is rather difficult. Theorem 2 in Angluin's [Queries and Concept Learning](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~lreyzin/f16_mcs548/angluin88.pdf) shows that $2^n-1$ queries are required even if there are only $2n$ objects and $n+1$ minterms. See the paper for other models in which your problem can be solved efficiently.

Comment: Thanks - this was very helpful.For concrete algorithms, this paper looks promising: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0792v1.pdf